# NSThread detachNewThreadSelector: Crash only in release build in Xcode 7 + Swift 2.0

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, swift, nsthread

I have a framework that calls back methods in the **`AppDelegate`** using **`detachNewThreadSelector:`** of **`NSThread`**, which looks something like this:

```
private func bridgeSelector(selector: String?, object: String?) {
        if selector != nil && responder != nil {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                NSThread.detachNewThreadSelector(Selector(
                    selector!),
                    toTarget: self.responder!,
                    withObject: object
                )
            })
        }
    }
```

The **`responder`** is a `var` assigned to `self` in **`AppDelegate`** when the framework's class was initialized.

The application ran without problem in the debug build, but crashed at once when the above is called if it's in release build. (It also crashed when I turned off optimize in the release build.)

I'm using Xcode 7 beta and Swift 2.0. (I knew it's beta, but it's the only beta supports Swift 2.)

**EDIT -** I end up use closure instead of the `detachNewThreadSelector:`. Works in both builds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I use to replace the above one is using `Closure`.

In the class of the framework, I declared a closure variable:

```
class FrameworkClass {

    public var methodOfAnotherClass: ((sender: AnyObject?) -> ())?

    func asyncMethod() {
        // Done with the work.
        let msg = "From Russia, with love."
        methodOfAnotherClass!(sender: msg)
    }
}
```

Then in the main class:

```
class main {

    func bond(objectFromRussia: AnyObject?) {
        if let msg = objectFromRussia as? String {
            Swift.print(msg)
        }
    }

    func callMeMaybe() {
        let aFrameworkClassObject = FrameworkClass()
        aFrameworkClassObject.methodOfAnotherClass = bond
        aFrameworkClassObject.asyncMethod()
    }

}
```

When `callMeMaybe:` is called, console should print `From Russia, with love.`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `respondsToSelector:` check there. It is dirty, but something like that. It is dirty i believe

```
func bridgeSelector(selector: String?, object: String?) {
    if let r = responder, let sel = selector where
        r.respondsToSelector(Selector(sel))
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            NSThread.detachNewThreadSelector(
                Selector(sel),
                toTarget: r,
                withObject: object
            )
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Cannot invoke 'detachNewThreadSelector' with an argument list of type '(String, toTarget: AnyObject, withObject: String?)'

Comment: Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Comment: And the crash location is in main-thread right when this method was called.

Comment: I assume that crash occurs as object doesn't respond to this selector

Comment: That's what I thought. But can't explain why it only happened in release build.

Comment: Thanks. Just tried, still crash at the same place and only in release build.